# Webstorm - Typescript, AngularJS and generator-ng-poly Getter/Setter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, gulp, webstorm

I've got the following file called **lobby-constants.ts**:

```
module lobby.constants {
  export class Constants {

    static get Default() : any {
      return {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:2999'
      };
    }
  }
}
```

and I am going to load it via:

```
.constant('appConstant', lobby.constants.Constants.Default);
```

unfortunately I get the following error message in Webstorm which makes perfectly sence, since gulp has ECMAScript version 3 as default output.

> app\lobby\constants\lobby-constants.ts(8,16): 1056 Accessors are only
>   available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.

Is there a way to change this particular setting in the gulpfile?

generator-ng-poly: https://github.com/dustinspecker/generator-ng-poly

Comment: The `generator-ng-poly` docs seem to imply that it uses Babel to support ES6 so... maybe they forgot to pass the ES5 target to `tsc` ? **Edit** Looks like there's an open issue about supporting ES6/ES2015 ~ https://github.com/dustinspecker/generator-ng-poly/issues/170

Comment: I was using the option "typescript" at that point. Is there a way implicitly declare ECMA 5 as output?

Answer (score 1):

In the generated `gulpfile.js` file, modify

```
config.tsProject = $.typescript.createProject({
  declarationFiles: true,
  noExternalResolve: false
});
```

to have an `out` option passed like

```
config.tsProject = $.typescript.createProject({
  declarationFiles: true,
  noExternalResolve: false,
  out: 'es5'
});
```

That's for older generated projects. Newer projects are generated with a config.tsSourceProject and config.tsTestProject in `gulpfile.js` that will both need to be modified with the out option.

Comment: I've made the changes you described but I still get the same error message. Might there be another setting which I need to change?